# pressure switch activated LED to stay lit for 10s

Tags: sensor, delay

RC circuit with pressure switch, 9V battery and gumdrop LED (31ma) with 470uF capacitor, stays on for 1s, want 10s but not larger capacitor, ideally would like variable time, 5-10s

Comment: Post a schematic!

Comment: All you want is a circuit that will turn on an LED for 5-10 seconds, and then turn it off, when the pressure switch closes? Do you want this retriggerable, so that if the pressure switch opens and then closes _before_ the time period expires then the time period is reset so that it will be another 5-10 seconds after that? You don't say. Unfortunately, a circuit can't be designed properly without knowing what you want in all circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

If this is more-or-less your present circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fal3A8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can add an emitter follower and change the time constant independently of the LED current:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fobVGR.png)</sup>

Component values are very approximate- adjust for your desired visual effect.

There are much nicer ways to do this, with a timer or a one-shot or even a microcontroller, some of which draw little battery current in quiescent state, but this is the simplest and closest to what I'm guessing is your current circuit.